# Is there any way I can create PayPal button inside button factory right from my website?

Tags: php, paypal

May look insane. But a try,

Instead of creating Add to cart or Buy now button by using button builder manually inside the paypal.com website, can I do that automatically from my website using POST or by using API?

`<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX">` Sample syntax of the button  ID when creating a hosted button inside PayPal.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of... You can create a button which is not hosted. It would be a form POST:

Here is button HTML that you can alter for each of your items. This is a complex button with all of the options. These are not all necessary:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="ABCDEFG1234"> <-- Put your merchant ID here
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Tell me things about your order">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.mystore.com/success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.mystore.com/cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="13.000">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.mystore.com/pp_ipn">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">Size</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="S">S $1.00 USD</option>
    <option value="M">M $1.00 USD</option>
    <option value="L">L $2.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color">Color</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="Red">Red </option>
    <option value="White">White </option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Custom Text">Custom Text</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="S">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="L">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The 2nd input is name="business" and the value is your merchant ID. You *CAN* put your email here, but its not recommended, because bots can scrape the page and get your email, which is never usually a good thing. To get your merchant ID:

1. Log into PayPal.com
2. Go to the Profile link at the top, and a dropdown menu will come down
3. Click My Personal Info at the top of the dropdown menu
4. Your Merchant ID is the option 2nd from the bottom

Hope this helped!

[Edit] Bit more info:

Here are the docs explaining all of the HTML variable names, usages, etc.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

[/Edit]

[Edit2]
To add a bit to this, there is the Button Manager API's as well. On this page, the 3rd section down is Button Manager (or you can do a find on page for Button Manager)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/

This may be what you're looking for.
[/Edit2]

Comment: I am aware of this method. But since this is open to be intrusion by altering the code, I tried using hosted buttons. But I have large number of items.